# C# null propagation and checking method invokation

Tags: c#, wcf

I have Class which could be nullable and before method call I am checking if class is not null and than calling void method with null propagation. i want to check if method was called or class instance was null and method was not called.

```
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://ServerAddress":8096/ServiceInterface");
var instance = new ServiceClient<IServiceInterface>(endpoint);
if(instance.WcfServiceClient?.Call(ticketTicketsCount) != null)
```

i want to achieve this condition.

Answer (score 0):

The null propaganding operator (or elvis operator in slang) should only be used if you don't care if something gets called or not.
What about that:

```
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://ServerAddress":8096/ServiceInterface")
var serviceClient = new ServiceClient<IServiceInterface>(endpoint);
var wcfClient = serviceClient.WcfServiceClient;

if(wcfClient == null)
{
   //Not called
}
else
{
   wcfClient.Call(ticketTicketsCount);
   //called
}
```

**EDIT:**
It seems that you are suffering from the "less code is better" sickness :P
You should always remember **KISS** (**K**eep **i**t **s**imple **s**tupid)
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

I already edited your question (curently awaiting peer review) because the code is not very readable. Don't try to squeeze a lot of code in as few lines as possible. **Aim for maximum readability.**

Comment: In instance.WcfServiceClient I'm checking if service is pingable than i call service method. if not pingable I'm returning null.

Comment: ok, so what is the issue with the code above? It only calls if your service is pingable. (Based on what you just said)

Comment: I'm searching compact way to achieve this goal

Comment: with null propagation service ping also will be called twice?

Comment: @YoskaKapianidze I am not sure what you are trying to acomplish. I modified my answer. If this still doesn't answer your question you may better explain your goal by modifying your question.